# Where to find reference for the energy method $\lambda u- \Delta u=f(x) \hspace{1cm} x \in \Omega, \hspace{1cm}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

Why do I need to multiply by the function w in the energy method to guaranty at most one solution?

This is the example
$\lambda  u- \Delta u=f(x) \hspace{1cm} x \in \Omega, \hspace{1cm} u=0 \hspace{0.1cm} \in \partial \Omega)$

I am applying the energy method: For this, I suppose there are two solutions $u$ and $v$ and construct $w=u-v$. 
In the process, I multiply $w$ by the whole expression i.e.

$\lambda  w^2- w\Delta w=0$

After some calculation, I check that $u=v$. But, where is the explanation of the method that explains that it is necessary to multiply by w?

Comment: Because multiplication by $w$ allows you to use integration by parts on the $w \Delta w$ term to get an equation that is positive (negative) semi definite i.e $$\int_{\Omega} \lambda w^{2} - w \Delta w = \text{boundary terms that vanish} + \int_{\Omega} \lambda w^{2} + \lvert \nabla w \rvert^{2} = 0$$ As you have a sum of positive terms equalling zero, $w \equiv 0$.

Comment: @mattos thanks, very motivating and clear explanation. Also, Do you know where can I find a reference that explains the "why" of the method?

Comment: I don't know of any reference that will explain what I just told you off the top of my head, maybe Evans' PDEs book will have something. I suppose if you google 'energy method' you might get some good information. However, what I explained above becomes obvious once you have studied [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations) and [functional derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative).